# Openshift Container Storage - copy file to persistent volume

Tags: file, copy, openshift, ocs

I am trying to copy some files to a persistent volume that will be later on mounted on a pod. In the example I am looking at they use NFS PV and it is quite simple as I can access the NFS file system associated with a PV and I can add files to it.
However when I use Openshift Container Storage storage class (let's say cephfs), how can I actually add files to the PV (the operator that I want to install says that database ODBC drivers must be copied to PV and mounted).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mount the PV in a different pod, and "oc cp" the files in, or "oc rsh ..." and curl/wget/scp from inside the pod to the local volume mount.

On an existing pod, you can also create a sidecar container with, e.g, busybox to mount the same PV and provide file copy tools if they're not present in the primary container.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below command to copy files from local to ocp PV.

`oc cp <source_path> <env_name>/<pod_name>:/<folder_name>/<sample_file>.<extension>`

example :
move to the folder from which you want to copy the file. let's say you have a test folder in which you have test.json that you want to copy so here would be the command.

`cd test`

`oc cp . env1/pod1:/cepfs/test.json`